# have a clue generate SHA1 from C# , but cant implement at PHP

Tags: c#, php

i have a clue code like this, and i dont understand C# , only know JS and PHP

here clue code for generate SHA1

```
ComputeSHA1(String.Format("key|{a}|{b}{c}", "post", userid, pin, password))).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_')
```

can someone help me for convert into php ?

im trying

```
$sign = str_replace('+','-', str_replace('/','_', rtrim(base64_encode(sha1("key|{a}|{b}{c},post,2,1234,admin",true)),'=')));
echo $sign;
```

but no luck

Comment: You might want to include the definition of `ComputeSHA1` else we can only guess at it.

Comment: `String.Format("key|{a}|{b}{c}", "post", userid, pin, password)` this looks wrong - where did you get this?

Comment: @John_ReinstateMonica ComputeSHA1 is not for php, php only using sha1(

Comment: @germi developer tell me , but he using c#

userid,pin and password will be replace from post variable

Comment: ComputeSHA1 is not a built-in .NET method. Without showing us the implementation, how on Earth could we possibly advise you what is wrong with your PHP equivalent? For example, what if you're passing double-byte characters but using ASCII string encoding to get bytes to pass to the hashing algorithm. You keep going about what you want but don't provide us with what we need to help you.

Comment: Please update this question to include the implementation details of `ComputeSHA1`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming replacements are to be of Base64 URL encoding

```
using (SHA1Managed sha1 = new SHA1Managed())
    {
        var hash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes($"key|{userid}|{pin}{password}"));
        return Convert.ToBase64String(hash).TrimEnd('=').Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_');
    }
```

Comment: I checked PHP SHA1 function it is returning `Hex` string of hash, what you intended to get is `Base64UrlSafe` encoded string, try converting HEX encoded to URL safe base encodoing